# Create Azure VM with a Windows Server license I have

Tags: azure

The options I currently get when trying to create a new Azure VM is to include Windows Server and I will have to pay for it. I have a windows server license and i would like to use it in my Azure VM instead.

How can I do that ?

Comment: There is this article that stated they will be allowing this but not sure if it is available yet. Have a look [Here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-debuts-new-bring-your-own-windows-server-license/)

Comment: Thank you, I haven't found a reference yet that confirms its availability.